# Permanent (301) redirect in nancy module

Tags: redirect, module, http-status-code-301, nancy

I am re-writing an old web site in Nancy.

I have a lot of old urls like this:  /thepagename.aspx

I was wondering if there is any good reason why I can't handle the legacy urls like this in a module?

```
Get["/theoldpagename.aspx"] = _ => Response.AsRedirect("~/new-page-name")
            .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently);
```

On the host I don't have full access to IIS but I can do this in the web.config.
Is there any good reason why I shouldn't do the above instead?

Comment: In my opinion that's fine

Comment: I'd use a separate Nancy module for the redirects, to keep the new stuff clean.

Comment: thanks, I've gone with it and created a Redirect module to handle these. There's only about 50 so shouldn't be a big deal.